# Windows Disk Management: disk partition is disabled

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, mbr

There is an HDD (WD10EZRX SATA 1 TB). Partition style: MBR. It is divided into three partitions. Two small and one large main partition. For some reason, this main partition is not available. It is not mounted to the system. If you right-click on it, then all items in the context menu are disabled except for Delete Volume. Even the Properties item is unavailable.

[image: Disk Management screenshot]

Is it possible to connect this partition or at least recover data from it?

Comment: You could use Windows `diskpart` command-line tool for getting more details on the disk. I would assume that the partition types are somehow wrong and therefore Windows can't manager them (only delete). Alternatively boot a Live-Linux system (e.g. from USB-stick) and check if the partitions are usable in Linux.

Comment: It doesn't appear to have a file system on it.  Am I not seeing something? ... and recover data?  I myself trust [testdisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download).  I have recovered thousands of files using this free tool.  If it saves your a*s, I suggest donating.  Oh.. and @Robert suggestion above ^ is really good.  That is also something that I might do.

Comment: Oh wait! .. it doesn't even have the format option!  DOUGH!  Yeah.. go with @Robert suggestion or download another partition manager to get more info.